# Protect API User Registration Endpoint used by Mobile App

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express, passport.js

I've been recently learning to use JWT to secure user endpoints for an API I am creating for my mobile application.

I currently have a **loginless system**, where the app user gets automatically registered on the server, then gets automatically authorized and issued a JWT to use for all further requests. All the routes are protected except the following 2:

1) POST /register:
The most important one, that I could not figure out how to protect. Anyone with the URL can currently pass any login/password combo and consider himself registered, and subsequently obtain a JWT. **I want to limit registrations to only my mobile application. How can I do that?**

2) POST /auth: Used to validate login/password and issue JWT. I guess it's ok to remain unprotected if I manage to protect the registration. But I do actually want to restrict it to my mobile client as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To protect the registration, it is not enough to protect the end-point. Users always able to make `requests`to your server.

You should do: Email validation, or Phone validations, or using Captcha. This will Prevents robots from registering.

Recommended Captcha Library by Google:

- https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Comment: It's a loginless system for a mobile application. I don't ask the user for any information, but generate a unique UUID and secret on each device.